# How to make this theme no-responsive?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport, television

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=https%3A//wagglepets.com/new-home-design/&w=533&h=853&a=24&s=1

I don't want it to adjust for browser size.

If it is a big screen is there a way of making the whole thing bigger proportionately (including all elements) and on mobile it makes it smaller proportionately and then just let the user zoom in so everything is the same as it would be usually proportionately speaking.

I have been fiddling about with viewport minimum/maximum scale hoping this would change things but to no avail.

***EDIT***

I think the best way for me to do this would have been to put all objects at a fixed width in pixels rather than as a %.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried CSS Media queries?
 You can specify different behaviors for different screen configurations

This should be helpful:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp